# i am getting double jsonarray in android to extract and not getting result back

Tags: android, json

[image: My result image of android app]

this is the image of the output i am getting i need to get the value of name. The code i am trying is

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray);

 String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
```

But it isn't working. Can anyone help me regarding this
Thanks alot

This is the backend php code on which i am working on

```
$aircraftId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'aircraftId');
            $arr = array();
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM temp WHERE aircraft_id = :aid");
            $stmt->execute(array(':aid' => $aircraftId));
            $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $x = 0;
            foreach ($data as $in)
            {
                $arr[$x][] = array(
                'id' =>  $data->id,
                'name'  => $data->name,
                'label'  => $data->label,
                'description'  => $data->description,
                'type'  => $data->type,
                'value'  => $data->value,
                'deliminator'  => $data->deliminator,
                'deliminator2'  => $data->deliminator2,
                'title'  => $data->title,
                'part_number'  => $data->part_number,
                'serial_number'  => $data->serial_number,
                'mm'  =>$data->mm,
                'cost' =>$data->cost,
                'category' =>$data->category,
                'timeInstall' => $data->timeInstall,
                'customType' => $data->customType,
                'engineNumber' => $data->engineNumber,
                'activateMargin' => $data->activateMargin,
                'margin0' => $data->margin0,
                'margin1' => $data->margin1,
                'margin2' => $data->margin2,
                'margin3' => $data->margin3,
                'displayField' => $data->displayField,
                'tso1' => $data->tso1,
                'tso2' => $data->tso2,
                'tso3' => $data->tso3,
                'tso4'  => $data->tso4,
                'interval1' =>  $data->interval1,
                'interval2' => $data->interval2,
                'interval3' => $data->interval3,
                'interval4' => $data->interval4,
                'rmg1' => $data->rgm1,
                'rmg2' => $data->rmg2,
                'rmg3' => $data->rmg3,
                'rmg4' => $data->rmg4,
                'lcw1' => $data->lcw1,
                'lcw2' => $data->lcw2,
                'lcw3' => $data->lcw3,
                'lcw4' =>  $data->lcw4
            );
                $x = $x+1;
            }

            echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: add your code  Json Parsing logic is correct

Comment: can you post your backend script which you are using to get get json response.

Comment: I think this is due to your not well formatted JSON string. Add your JSON response here which you are showing in toast and how are you doing parsing in java code ?

Comment: added the backend code also Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not parsing the response right.
Remember "[" shows JSONArray started and in the response you have two [ which means you need to get two JSONArrays before you get JSONObject and eventualy data inside that JSONObject.

Try this

```
try {
        JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONArray innerArray = responseArray.getJSONArray(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < innerArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = innerArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
            String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

@Tabish's code is even better if you are getting multiple arrays within the first array.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is correct `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);`

Next statement should be a for loop. Iterating through the jsonArray object. For eg :

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
 JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJsonObject(i);
 String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
}
```

Can you please try this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two JsonArrays and then the JsonObject Came up so

```
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray(results);
for (int i  = 0 ; i< jsonArray.length() ; i++){
    JsonArray jsonArray1 = jsonArray.get(i);
      for(int j = 0 ; j < jsonArray1.length() ; j++){
          JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray1.get(j);
          String name  = jsonObject.getAsString("name");
      }
}
```